# How to sort an array from another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, lodash

There are two arrays I have created in my modules. That has been inserted below.

```
var a = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var b = [{name:"Fri", value:10}, {name:"Thu", value:5}];
```

My requirement is I want to create another array with order of array "a". If the name is not contain in "b" array, I need to push value 0 into an new array.

Expected result,

```
var result = [0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0];
```

My Code,

```
const result= [];
    _.map(a, (el, i) => {
      if(b[i] !== undefined) {
        if(el === b[i].name) {
          result.push(b[i].value);
        } else {
          result.push(0);
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: @MattThurston, I have updated the code. But the output still I'm getting wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is helpful here

```js
var a = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var b = [{name:"Fri", value:10}, {name:"Thu", value:5}];

var res = a.map(s => {
  var bMatch = b.find(o => o.name === s);// returns found object or undefined
  return bMatch ? bMatch.value : 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up the value inside of `b` by iterating through all elements of `b`, in order to know if it exists.

I would recommend adjusting the structure of `b` to look like:

```
var b = {
  "Fri": 10,
  "Thu": 5,
}
```

If that's not an option, then here's how you could do it with your current structure:

```js
var a = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var b = [{name:"Fri", value:10}, {name:"Thu", value:5}];

const result = a.map((aVal) => {
    var found = 0; // default to 0 if not found
    // edit: this iteration could be replaced with find in the other answer
    b.forEach((bVal) => { // try to find the day in b
       if (bVal.name === aVal) { // if the day is found 
          found = bVal.value; // set the found value to value field of b element
       }
    });
    return found;
 });

 console.log(result);
```